Change some text after compose.beginReply function in Thunderbird Add-On
I have Thunderbird addon that compose reply to message.
I need to change some text in the replied message.
The code below:
const fullMessage = await browser.messages.getFull(messageId);

        // Extracting the body of the message
         const body = getBodyFromParts(fullMessage.parts);
         if (!body) {
           console.warn("Message body not found:", fullMessage);
           continue;
         }

        // If text in HTML, will transform it
        if (/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(body)) {
          body = body
            .replace(/<\/p>/gi, "\n")      // Paragraph wrapping
            .replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, "\n") // Line Wrapping
            .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");      // Уtake the remaining HTML tags
        }

        // If the text is still stuck together, add line breaks
        if (!body.includes("\n")) {
          body = body.replace(/([.!?])\s+/g, "$1\n"); // Hyphenation after a period, exclamation or question
        }
              
        // Check for the presence of "[AGREE]"
        if (body.includes("[AGREE]")) {
          const newBody = body.replace("[AGREE]", "[AGREE]+");
          console.log("Text newBody after:", newBody);
        
          // Converting line breaks for HTML
          const htmlBody = newBody.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
          console.log("HTML version of newBody:", htmlBody);
               

          //Create a response message
          const composeDetails = await browser.compose.beginReply(message.id, 'replyToSender');
          
          // Set a new body for the response
          await browser.compose.setComposeDetails(composeDetails.id, { body: htmlBody, isPlainText: false });

I have reply message as below:
enter image description here
If use code without this line:
// Set a new body for the response
          await browser.compose.setComposeDetails(composeDetails.id, { body: htmlBody, isPlainText: false });

reply message looking as that:
enter image description here
But I need reply message see as on picture below:
enter image description here
I try to place code:
//Create a response message
const composeDetails = await browser.compose.beginReply(message.id, 'replyToSender');
console.log("Создано сообщение для ответа:", composeDetails.id);
    // Receive Full message
    const fullMessage = composeDetails;
    

    console.log("Full message:", fullMessage);

     // Extracting the body of the message
     const body = getBodyFromParts(fullMessage.parts);
     if (!body) {
       console.warn("Message body not found:", fullMessage);
       continue;
     }

before Extracting the body of the message.
And I have the error "Parts of message not found".
